# Show query result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I have a query:

```
$string = "SELECT COUNT(id) as sponsered FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id = 2 group by plan";
```

Which result in:

```
 sponsored plan
         2 gold
         1 silver
         1 mitra
```

This result is shown when I run this query in MySQL.

Now I want this result in PHP in an array data[] where

```
  data[0] contains 2
  data[1] contains 1
  data[2] contains 1
```

I have tried this

```
$string = "SELECT COUNT(id) as sponsered FROM $database.$mem where parent_id = 2 group by plan";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $string);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $data['sponsered'];
}
```

But it results in `data['sponsered']` containing `211`

It would be better if this can be done without using any loop.

Comment: You really want to be extra super careful that things like `$database` and `$mem` are not controlled by the user here. Why is that information so variable?

Comment: Can you post your full code

Comment: @tadman i didn't understood your comment but the variable are there because i when there are so many queries and when  change database name due to a reason...its a headache to change all queries

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you need to be absolutely certain that users are not able to control those values. When I see queries like this I immediately ask a few questions: Is specifying the database name necessary given you're probably already using it? Do you have a multitude of tables to store data instead of a single table with some kind of grouping column? Do you check these values against a list of known-good table names before using them?

Comment: Why are javascript and html tagged? Neither seem to be addressed here

Comment: sorry @PatrickEvans it was automatically tagged

Comment: @chris85 because i had tried this   $string = "SELECT COUNT(id) as sponsered FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id = 2 group by plan";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $string);
  
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
   {
    echo $data['sponsered'];
   }

but it results in data['sponsered'] containing 211

Comment: What happened with that?

Comment: @chris85 when i echo data['sponsered'] it printed "211" buti want data[0] = 2; data[1]=1; data[2] =1;

Comment: @chris85 thanks it worked,    such a silly mistake...! answer this as your answer plz. i will mark it correct

Comment: You have one column in the query, and two columns in the result. How does that work?

Comment: @jolly Please dont forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop assign the values to array.

```
$string = "SELECT COUNT(id) as sponsered FROM $database.$mem where parent_id = 2 group by plan"; 
$res = mysqli_query($con, $string); 
$data = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $data[] = $result['sponsered']; 
} 
print_r($data);
```

Output:

data[0] contains 2
data[1] contains 1
data[2] contains 1

Comment: shows error  Undefined offset: 0 in data[0], 1 in data[1], 2 in data[2]

Answer (score 0):

Your display is correct you just need a separator so the data isn't all clumped. In a browser:

```
echo $data['sponsered'] . "<br>";
```

in your loop should do it, or command line,

```
echo $data['sponsered'] . PHP_EOL;
```

should do it.

As is it throws `2`, then `1`, then `1` which views as `211`.

Comment: just one more thing:- as this is in while i cant print it as G-2 S-1 M-1. can u change your answer according to that

Comment: Where do the letters come from? Are those the `plan`s?

Comment: i want to add them myself. they are also short names for gold silver and mitra

Comment: How do they relate to the numbers though

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

Please refrain from passing data directly into query in a prepare statement, use `? or :` as deemed necessary.

Below is a sample code:

```
<?php
    $table_name = $table; //not recommended to pass table_name as variable, unless necessary.
    $parent_id = 2;
    $p = $plan;

    $string = "SELECT COUNT(id) as sponsered FROM $table_name where parent_id = ? group by ?";
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare($string))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('is',  $parent_id, $p);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($sponsored, $plan);
        $stnt->store_result();

        $html ='';

        while ($stmt->fetch() !== FALSE)
        {
            // Do what you like with the variables here, i.e. $sponsored, $plan
            $html .= "<table>
                        <th> Sponsored </th>
                        <th> Plan</th>
                        <tr>
                        <td>$sponsored</td>
                        <td>$plan</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>";
        }
        else {
            die("Query failed");
        }
        var_dump($html);
    }
?>
```

NOTE: If your result from your question is just an HTML *(table/column)*, you don't need to do bind, you can just output the HTML formatted.

Comment: You can't bind tables/columns.

Comment: @chris85 I thought he retrieved data and output as html

Comment: Thanks @Peter Mortensen

Comment: @chris85 nice catch

Comment: `group by ?` is the same scenario. They should be passed against a whitelist though.

Answer (score -2):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)` to retreive the data as numeric array

Comment: Question says nothing about `mysqli`. It's best to ask rather than presume.